# Using raw string properly to send commands over SSH in Python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have a long long command to send over SSH using Paramiko and I need to wrap the string using "r" parameter but the IDE still tells me it's not written fine.
The string is something like that:

```
somecommand get -n somestuff sa/management --template='{{range .secrets}}{{printf "%s\n" .name}}{{end}}'
```

I tried doing:

```
command = r'somecommand get -n somestuff sa/management --template='{{range .secrets}}{{printf "%s\n" .name}}{{end}}'
```

But got an error.
This is probably something super easy to do....

Comment: What kind of template code is this? It's very hard to guess how this `\n` will finally be rendered. Especially without an error message. It's also strange that your error didn't come with an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are missing a quote at the end of your string.
The second problem is that you can't use quotes inside a string like that.

```
r'some'thing'
```

won't work while

```
r'some"thing'
```

will work.
Since you have quotes in quotes inside the string use a triple-quoted string instead:

```
r"""some"thi'ng"""
```

So a working version of your string would be:

```
command = r"""somecommand get -n somestuff sa/management --template='{{range .secrets}}{{printf "%s\n" .name}}{{end}}'"""
```

Comment: Brilliant, mate! Thanks a lot!